# How do i lookup a file under playbook_dir in Ansible?

Tags: file, ansible, lookup

I have a file foo.txt under my {{ playbook_dir }}/vars folder.

I'm trying to assign the contents of the file to a variable "filecon"

Below is my playbook:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  vars:
     filecon: "{{ lookup('file', 'hostvars[playbook_dir]/vars/foo.txt') }}"
  tasks:
     - debug: msg="the value of foo.txt is {{ contents }}"
```

However, the above playbook run fails with the below error:

```
TASK [debug]
******************************************************************************************************************************************************************  
[WARNING]: Unable to find 'hostvars[playbook_dir]/vars/foo.txt' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths) 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ lookup('file', 'hostvars[playbook_dir]/vars/foo.txt') }}'. 
Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. 
Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: hostvars[playbook_dir]/vars/foo.txt"}
```

I tried the following but they all fail.

```
  filecon: "{{ lookup('file', 'vars[playbook_dir]/vars/foo.txt') }}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this syntax:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    filecon: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ hostvars[\"localhost\"][\"playbook_dir\"] }}/vars/foo.txt') }}"

  tasks:
  - debug: 
      msg: "the value of foo.txt is: {{ filecon }}"
```

hope it helps.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank  you for the answer @ilias-sp